What is Outlook 2021 MSO exactly?
A customer is having issues with an application sending emails through Outlook via MAPI. The Outlook version displays as 'Microsoft Outlook 2021 MSO (Version 16.0.15731.20822) 32-Bit'
What Office SKU is this? Is it a non-365 linked version ?

Not entirely sure, but I think this is Microsoft Outlook, as separate package, not part of the Microsoft Office suite.

It's the "perpetual license" Office 2021 package (single i.e. non-volume-license; VL versions of Office 2021 would say "LTSC").
All year-named Office versions are perpetual-license and non-365-linked (as the whole idea of Office 365 is continuous updates without discrete releases).

The version you mentioned, Microsoft Outlook 2021 MSO (Version 16.0.15731.20822) 32-Bit, is part of the Office 2021 suite. This is a standalone, perpetual license version of Office, meaning it is not linked to an Office 365 (now Microsoft 365) subscription) More information: https://usercomp.com/news/1436289/outlook-2021-mapi-email-sending-issues
